# Eclipse launch configuration as separate toolbar button with icon

Tags: eclipse

I have created quite a few launch configurations, which start, stop, reload a JBoss server as well as build an EAR and deploy it.

Now I would like to have them **as separate buttons** on a preferably separate toolbar (or the same toolbar as the dropdown "Run as...", "Debug as...", "External tools" and "Launch" button).

**Is it possible to achieve this somehow?**

Comment: That sounds like what you're looking for: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/launcher-extension

Comment: Thanks. I will checkout this plugin and https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner . Thanks.. If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following plug-ins don't offer exactly what you want, but may be helpful:

- The [**Launcher Extension**](https://github.com/pedrosans/launcher-extension) adds **two buttons** to the main toolbar: one to run the **corresponding JUnit test** of the Java class opened in the active editor and a second button (green heart) to run or debug the **launch configuration previously selected in the button pull-down menu**.
- The [**Eclipse Runner**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner) (which you found yourself) provides the ***Runner* view** (instead of main toolbar buttons) which displays **multiple launch configurations which can be grouped by categories**.

If you want to **write your own plug-in** for multiple buttons, the [source code of the Launcher Extension shows how to add buttons to the main toolbar](https://github.com/pedrosans/launcher-extension/blob/master/launcher-extension-plugin/plugin.xml#L47-L79). If you want to [add the buttons dynamically (e. g. when the server is running), this example project might be helpful](https://github.com/rage5474/de.ragedev.example.dynamictoolbar/).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, Eclipse 4.22 (Dec. 2021) comes with:

> ### [Launch Configuration View](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/platform.php#launch-config-view)
>
> The new Launch Configuration View allows quick access to all your launch configurations without the need to enter the launch dialogs.
>
> [image: Launch view -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/images/launch-config-view2.png]
>
> You can launch (run, debug, profile, etc.) as well as terminate and/or relaunch running configurations directly from the view.

The view also provides API which allows third party contributions to hook into the view and provide "`launchables`".

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved by writing eclipse plugin project. Which internally provides Tools/buttons and add functionality on each button to perform certain actions. This would require some idea of Eclipse plugin development, with SWT, JFace.

Run your project as eclipse application to see/debug your changes. Once you are satisfied, then export you plugin project as deployable feature

[image]

Place exported jar into eclipse ->plugin folder. Launch eclipse again. This will show button you have developed in eclipse plugin project.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So basically I either have to write my own plugin or find one that suites my needs - the Eclipse IDE cannot do this natively it seems. What I wanted, is to have some of the menu items in e.g. "Launch" or "External Tools" configuration become separate buttons with an icon. apparently it's not possible without plugins.

Comment: Telling the OP to 'write a plug-in' without even describing which Eclipse APIs are necessary to do what they want is not a helpful answer.

Comment: @Igor I was not aware of this plugin, which provides extension to launcher. But if you want more modifications in eclipse UI, such as adding a different toolbar. It can be achieved by writing eclipse plugin. Because for every need, there may not be available plugin. 

Writing a plug-in is not straight forward. It requires background, which can not be described in single post. Refer tutorial for this:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html